# A basic question on Lindeberg and Lyapunov condition

Tags: probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems, central-limit-theorem

Suppose along with independence in each row of a triangular array, it is given that in each row random variables are identically distributed then what Lindeberg and Lyapunov condition reduces to ? This is Billingsley problem.

As far as Lindeberg condition is concerned, I think as $n$ tends to infinity the number of terms in each row will go to infinity. I don't know what to do with Lyapunov's condition. Any hint will be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With notations of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindeberg%27s_condition), $s_n^2=n$ (assuming WLOG the variance is $1$). Then Lindeberg condition reduces to 
$$\mathbb E[(X_0-\mathbb E(X_0))^2\chi(|X_0-\mathbb E(X_0)|\gt \varepsilon\sqrt n],$$
which is equivalent to $X_0\in\mathbb L^2$.

Lyapunov's condition is in turn equivalent to $\mathbb E|X_0|^{2+\delta}$ is finite for some positive $\delta$, which is more restrictive.

Comment: What is $X_0$ ? The set over which $|X_{nk}| > \epsilon s_n$ can be different for each random variable in the array although they are identically distributed. In that case should we take intersection ?

Comment: No, $X_0$ is the first random variable of the sequence $(X_k)_{k\geqslant 0}$.

Comment: the set where the first random variable differ from its mean by $\epsilon \sqrt(n)$ may be diferent from sets for other random variables in the array. how are you then summing up all the expectations ?

Comment: Yes, but I use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, so are $f(X)$ and $f(Y)$ for a Borel measurable function $f$. Since the means are the same, we use this with $f(x)=(x-\mathbb E(X_0))^2\chi_{(\varepsilon\sqrt n,\infty)}$.

Comment: But, what extra we are getting using Lindeberg condition ? We already have that all the random variables have finite second moment.